# Swift check max value and use

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have Double array

```
var array = [2.50, 2.51, 2.41, 2,1, 1.8, 1.3, 2.9, 3.0]
```

I need to check max value

```
let maxTuple = array.max()
print(maxTuple)
```

But it's print me all array   //2.50, 2.51, 2.41, 2,1, 1.8, 1.3, 2.9, 3

Then if I get current max value I want to make like this

```
var difference = (maxTuple - 2.50)  //0.5
if (difference > 0.1) {
    print("> 0.1")
} else if (difference > 0.2) {
    print("> 0.2")
} else if (difference > 0.3..0.5) {
    print("> 0.3..0.5")   
} else if (difference > 1) {
    print("> 1")
}
```

How currently in swift i can do it?

Comment: You code prints `"Optional(3.0)\n"`

Comment: array.max() should work . you may be doing something else.

Comment: Note that maxTuple is an optional therefore you can't do any math without unwrapping it first `if let maxTuple = array.max() {` . Btw 0.3..0.5 it is not a valid range and the correct way to check if it contains your double is `0.3...0.5 ~= difference`

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, maybe I can do this using case? without if

Comment: Yes a switch case syntax would be much better than a sequence of IFs

Comment: Note: you'll need to reverse the order of your `if` or `switch` cases, because it stops when you hit a match, so `difference > 0.1` will succeed before any of the other cases which will never be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that maxTuple is an optional therefore you can't do any math without unwrapping it first:

```
if let maxTuple = array.max() { 
      // your code
}
```

Btw 0.3..0.5 it is not a valid range and the correct way to check if it contains your double is:

```
if 0.3...0.5 ~= difference {
    // your code
}
```

---

```
let array = [2.50, 2.51, 2.41, 2,1, 1.8, 1.3, 2.9, 3.0]

if let maxValue = array.max() {
    print(maxValue)
    let difference = maxValue - 2.5  // 0.5
    switch difference {
    case 0.0...0.1:
        print("greater than 0.0 and less than 0.1")
    case 0.1...0.2:
        print("greater than 0.1 and less than 0.2")
    case 0.2...0.3:
        print("greater than 0.2 and less than 0.3")
    case 0.3...1.0:
        print("greater than 0.3 and less than 1.0") // "greater than 0.3 and less than 1.0\n"
    case 1.0...:
        print("greater than 1.0")
    default:
        print("negative value")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in using Array's `max()` function. Maybe there is some confusion based on what output you are looking at, possibly in a playground? For instance you should see the following where the last line of output is the expected max value:

[image]

Since `max()` does produce an optional (as denoted by `Optional(3.0)`), wherever you end up using this value you may want to safely unwrap it using `guard` of `if let`:

```
guard let maxValue = array.max() else {
    return
}
//Do something with maxValue
```